# Open File Picker in snap view of Metro Style App

Tags: microsoft-metro, filepicker

When I try to open file picker on snap view in Metro Style App, exception occurs and exception dialog box was shown. How to solve that problem? Is there any good idea? I want my app works properly even on snap view.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Before opening the file picker, you must try to leave the snapped mode.

Here is the code I use:

```
var ready = true;
if (ApplicationView.Value == ApplicationViewState.Snapped)
    ready = ApplicationView.TryUnsnap();
if (!ready)
    return;
```

Comment: great!!!.It works properly. So it means that file open picker couldn't be opened in snap view. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

The SDK samples available on msdn use the following snippet

```
// FilePicker APIs will not work if the application is in a snapped state.
// If an app wants to show a FilePicker while snapped, it must attempt to unsnap first
bool unsnapped = ((ApplicationView::Value != ApplicationViewState::Snapped) || ApplicationView::TryUnsnap());
if (!unsnapped)
{
    // Unsnapping failed
}
```